# Using cgconfig for thread and process sharing (cpu limit)

Tags: centos, cgroups

I have set the following limits for a user in the cgconfig rules

```
# cat /etc/cgconfig.conf
group group_mahmood {
  cpu {
    cpu.shares = 300;
  }
  memory {
    memory.limit_in_bytes = 1073741824;
  }
}
# cat /etc/cgrules.conf
mahmood     cpu,memory grou_mahmood/
# service cgred restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart cgred.service
# service cgconfig restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart cgconfig.service
```

Now, when I run the stress command as `stress --cpu  8 --timeout 20`, the output of top is

```
28685 mahmood   20   0    7312    100      0 R 100.0  0.0   0:11.41 stress
28686 mahmood   20   0    7312    100      0 R  99.7  0.0   0:11.42 stress
28687 mahmood   20   0    7312    100      0 R  99.7  0.0   0:11.42 stress
28688 mahmood   20   0    7312    100      0 R  99.7  0.0   0:11.42 stress
28689 mahmood   20   0    7312    100      0 R  99.7  0.0   0:11.42 stress
28690 mahmood   20   0    7312    100      0 R  99.7  0.0   0:11.43 stress
28691 mahmood   20   0    7312    100      0 R  99.7  0.0   0:11.43 stress
28692 mahmood   20   0    7312    100      0 R  99.7  0.0   0:11.43 stress
```

It seems that the share limit is for threads (800%). How can I set the cpu limit to the number of processes? Actually I need both which should be logical OR together.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do?  What is the end result that you’d like to see?

Comment: I have set 300 as limit. I guess that is 3 threads per process. However, as you can see if I create 8 processes, I can bypass that limit. How can I create a limit on the number of processes?

Comment: That’s not what cpu.shares does.  It is a way to allocate how resources are divided amongst different Cgroups.  Since all of your processes are in the same cgroup, cpu.share won’t change how each thread gets cpu compared to each other. By default, a cgroup gets 1024 shares, so any other cgroup that asks for cpu while you run your stress will get more cpu relative to your entire cgroup, in the time period while it runs.

Comment: If you want to limit how many processes you can run, you don’t do that through cgroups.  That just controls how resources are shared between cgroups.  Use pam limits “nproc” to limit how many processes someone can run.  If you want to limit how many CPUs (or percentage of CPUs) a whole cgroup can use, use cpu quotas (cpu.cfs_quota_us).

Comment: OK. So, how can I achieve that? Limiting number of processes and threads in a process.

Comment: You can’t limit number of threads per process in Linux.  Threads are just essentially another process with shared address space in Linux. Maybe if you explained why you are trying to set limits, it might be easier to give a way to do it.

Comment: The purpose is to set cpu limit for a user. For example, I want to limit to 3 cores only. So, three 100% process or one process with 300% cpu usage are the most resources I want to grant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the [cpu.cfs_quota_us](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-cpu) tunable, not cpu.shares.  I linked to the RHEL6 documentation, but it’s the same if you are using `cgred` in RHEL7.

In systemd-related units, you would set the [CPUQuota](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#CPUQuota=) setting.  You could set it for the user-1001.slice (assuming the user’s UID is 1001) but there’s no generic way to do it in the version of systemd in RHEL7. (Templatable units don’t appear until later)

Comment: I can not find a document on how to add `CPUQuota ` in cgconfig.conf. It seems that it is a systemd option for limiting processes and not users.

Comment: Yes,  it is a systemd unit setting.  But .slice units are created per-user as part of systemd-logind, and there is a cgroup automatically created for users.  cgconfig/cgred are deprecated in systemd-based OSs.